# How to tell whether setup() is reading the setup.cfg?

Tags: python, setuptools

I got a Python project generated using [pyscaffold](https://github.com/pyscaffold/pyscaffold/) and I see the two standard main project files at the root `setup.py` and `setup.cfg`. I modified the `setup.cfg` file adding a line under the metadata section with `version=1.0.0`.

However, running `python setup.py develop` or `python setup.py sdist` I see in the outputs that the artifact name doesn't have the version I specified in the `setup.cfg`. I see the following:

```
Installed c:\users\SkyWalker\code\my_project\src
Processing dependencies for my_project==0.0.post0.dev1+g8386a10.dirty
Finished processing dependencies for my_project==0.0.post0.dev1+g8386a10.dirty
```

The distribution artifact has this `0.0.post0.dev1+g8386a10.dirty` version and I don't know where it's getting it from. How to tell whether `python.cfg` is read at all?

The pyscaffold generated `setup.py` looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
    Setup file for aqm_database_api.
    Use setup.cfg to configure your project.

    This file was generated with PyScaffold 3.2.3.
    PyScaffold helps you to put up the scaffold of your new Python project.
    Learn more under: https://pyscaffold.org/
"""
import sys

from pkg_resources import VersionConflict, require
from setuptools import setup

try:
    require('setuptools>=37.0')
except VersionConflict:
    print("Error: version of setuptools is too old (<37.0)!")
    sys.exit(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(use_pyscaffold=True)
```

so it's not loading `setup.cfg` explicitly, also the line `require('setuptools>=37.0')` fails every time, no matter what the version value there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyScaffold configures `setuptools` to use the version given by [`setuptools_scm`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools-scm/).
It means that, in order to change the version of your project you need to [use git to tag your project](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging). This is briefly described in https://pyscaffold.org/en/v3.3.x/features.html#versioning-and-git-integration.

I suppose that is the reason why changing `setup.cfg` will not change the version of the distribution created. A priori [`setuptools` should always read `setup.cfg`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/declarative_config.html).

To make sure `setuptools` is reading `setup.cfg` one experiment you can do is:

1. Make sure to remove any `*.egg-info` folder insude the root of your project or inside the `src` folder (to ensure you don't see a cached version).
2. Change something easy like author in the `setup.cfg` file
3. Build your package as you would do normally (`python setup.py bdist_wheel` for example)
4. Look for a new `<your-project>.egg-info` folder generated either in the root of your project or inside the `src` directory. Read the `PKG-INFO` there. You should be able to see your changes which proves `setuptools` is reading `setup.cfg` (otherwise the best option should be opening a ticket/issue with `setuptools`)